# background image rending outside html tag

Tags: html, background, height

I'm finding that there the background image of my body tag seems to be adding extra space at the bottom of the my web page in chrome.  Using the chrome inspector, this space does not belong to any tag, either as content, padding, margin or background.  I've tried changing heights, and increasing the size of elements, changing screen resolutions, removing the background image, and nothing seems to work.   I've checked that user style elements are being overridden.  The only thing I can't change is that a min-height that is being applied to a style tag in the html and body tags which I cannot change because it is part of a layout used on many pages.

Any thoughts?

Comment: post your html code or fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Give the part an ID and apply another min-height for that particular part.
is that page live ? Can I have a look at that please?